# Execution failure, unable to request: /deploy/jdbc-driver.txt

Tags: jdbc, configuration, jenkins, sonarqube

We used a Master/Slaves Jenkins architecture to perform SonarQube. When i runned my job,
Sonar was unable to execute and request the file /deploy/jdbc-driver.txt. I didn't find the reason, my properties files (Sonar server and sonar runner) seems to be good.

Could you help me please ?

Best regards,

David Parcoit

```
[IBP.DVB] $ D:\sonar-runner\bin\sonar-runner.bat -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver "-Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://ibicer05.srv-ib.dev:54301/sonar?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8" ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://ibicer00.srv-ib.dev:8090/sonar "-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=E:\Jenkins\workspace\DVB - Build Quotidien\IBP.DVB" -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.dotnet.excludeGeneratedCode=true -Dsonar.dotnet.buildConfigurations=Release -Dsonar.language=cs -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.gendarme.mode=skip -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0.0.0 -Dsonar.projectKey=IBP.DVB -Dsonar.ndeps.mode=skip -Dsonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=IBP.DVB.sln -Dsonar.projectName=DVB
D:\sonar-runner
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_05 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows Server 2012 6.2 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: D:\sonar-runner\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: E:\Jenkins\workspace\DVB - Build Quotidien\IBP.DVB\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 3.7.4
23:47:37.351 INFO  - Load batch settings
23:47:37.507 INFO  - User cache: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
23:47:37.523 INFO  - Install plugins
23:47:42.265 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 13.573s
Final Memory: 4M/44M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to request: /deploy/jdbc-driver.txt
ERROR: Caused by: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```